# How to position objects correctly in different resolutions in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, resolution

I'm writing an Android game and as I wanted it to be played in portrait mode I want the scale of the objects to remain the same in regards to the screen width. I think I managed to do that with this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class PowerPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        float w = Screen.width;
        float h = Screen.height;
        Vector2 position = (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(w * 0.9f, w * 0.53f)));
        float ratio = (w / h) / (9f / 16f);
        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x * ratio, position.y * ratio, 0);
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.localScale.x * ratio, gameObject.transform.localScale.y * ratio, gameObject.transform.localScale.z * ratio);
```

The issue is with the positioning. It changes and objects that should have relative distances from each other get messed up. Objects that should appear one above the other become too close and overlap.
The "position * ratio" was a test, it doesn't work well either with or without that. Here for example I had to items that I wanted to keep a consistent distance from the lower right end of the screen.

How can you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage calculation as orientationbase to scale. That represents a relational scaleability.

There is a false friend in your mind. The displays haves different dots per inch. Will say, this value may be included your calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your answer. What I did, which I thought should at least work if only the height resolution changes, was place the object as a multiply (a percentage, basically) of the screen width pixels, converted to world units, both at the X axis and at the Y axis. Having a *1 placement at each axis should place the object at the top right corner of the screen, so I figured if for example the resolution changes from 1920*1080 to 2340*1080, it would still place the object the same number of pixels from the bottom and sides. But it messes the placement up.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it differently.

A device has a screen resolution of X-axis, Y-axis, color depth and ppi / dpi.

You can buy a display with 1920x1080xColors with 6 "or 32". With large displays you have a lower pixel density compared to small displays.

A device itself only changes X and Y if you have an orientation sensor.

Landscape 1920x1080 becomes portrait 1080x1920.

When I take an iPhone, the display has a higher pixel density than the cheaper Android devices.

In mathematics there is the famous three-sentence that is suitable for calculating proportions.

You can query the value for the pixel density from the system. You can use this value for rescaling your buttons.

I work mostly with horizontal centering. So I keep the symmetry.

Comment: I'll need to see if there is a different calculation method involving DPI the gives correct results. Even though I don't understand what's the difference in the program's eye when the only thing it needs to know is how many pixels the screen have so it knows over how many different dots it displays the content, whether it is spread over a 5" display or 6.2". Also, if you provide an answer, it needs to be in one instance. If you want to add something you can edit it, or add a comment.

Comment: The dpi / ppi value is a given constant in Android. I tried a lot to find a decent solution. With a 32 "computer screen you are at 72 or 96 dpi. You can read well. With the Smarties you are between 120 (old) to 360 (new). This corresponds to a 3x reduction from new to old The legibility of the writing is also in the direction of the magnifying glass: 107 characters too many for EDIT